# A delayed differential equation system and its characteristic polynomial

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, nonlinear-system, stability-theory, bifurcation, delay-differential-equations

I have the following DDE system:

\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
    \dot{x}_{1} &= -\mu x_{1}(t) + a_{11}f_{11}(\int_{-\infty}^{t} F(t-s) x_{1}(s-\tau_{1})ds) + a_{12} f_{12}(x_{2}(t-\tau_{1}))) \\
    \dot{x}_{1} &= -\mu x_{2}(t) + a_{21}f_{21}(x_{1}(t-\tau_{1})) + a_{22} f_{22}(\int_{t}^{-\infty} F(t-s) x_{2} (s-\tau_{1} ds)) \\
    \dot{x_{3}} &= \mu x_{1}(t-\tau_{1}) - \mu x_{3}(t)\\
    \dot{x_{4}} &= \mu x_{2}(t-\tau_{1}) - \mu x_{4}(t)\\
\end{split}
\end{equation}

where

\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
    x_{3} &= \int_{-\infty}^{t} F(t-s) x_{1}(s - \tau_{1})ds\\
    x_{4} &= \int_{-\infty}^{t} F(t-s) x_{2}(s - \tau_{1})ds
\end{split}
\end{equation}

I want to do stability analysis. The equilibrium point is $\bar{\textbf{x}}=(\bar{x_{1}},\bar{x_{2}},\bar{x_{3}},\bar{x_{4}}) =  (0,0,0,0)$. We linearize the system around the point. Define $b_{ij} = a_{ij}\frac{df_{ij}}{x_{I}}$ and do the following substituions:

\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
    x_{1}(t) = \tilde{x_{1}}(t) - \bar{x_{1}}\\
    x_{2}(t) = \tilde{x_{2}}(t) - \bar{x_{2}}\\
    x_{3}(t) = \tilde{x_{3}}(t) - \bar{x_{3}}\\
    x_{4}(t) = \tilde{x_{4}}(t) - \bar{x_{4}}\\
\end{split}
\end{equation}

Since $\bar{\textbf{x}} = \textbf{0}$ we have $x_{i}(t) = \tilde{x_{I}}(t)$
Then we would have the following system:

\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
    \dot{x}_{1} &= -\mu x_{1}(t) + b_{11}(x_{3}(t)) + b_{12}(x_{2}(t-\tau_{1})) \\
    \dot{x}_{1} &= -\mu x_{2}(t) + b_{21}(x_{1}(t-\tau_{1})) + b_{22}(x_{4}(t)) \\
    \dot{x_{3}} &= \mu x_{1}(t-\tau_{1}) - \mu x_{3}(t)\\
    \dot{x_{4}} &= \mu x_{2}(t-\tau_{1}) - \mu x_{4}(t)\\
\end{split}
\end{equation}

Then we want to find characteristic equation and thus we calculate the following determinant:

\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\begin{vmatrix}
     \lambda + \mu & -b_{12} e^{\lambda \tau_{1}} & -b_{11} & 0\\ 
     -b_{21} e^{-\lambda \tau_{1}} & \lambda + \mu & 0 & -b_{22} \\
     -\mu e^{-\lambda \tau_{1}} &  0 & \lambda + \mu & 0 \\
     0 & -\lambda e^{-\lambda \tau_{1}} & 0 & \lambda + \mu \\
\end{vmatrix}
&= 0 
\end{split}
\end{equation}

My question is how do we get the determinant matrix? I know that we calculate $det(\lambda I - A)$ where A is the coefficient matrix of the system $(\dot{\textbf{x}} = A\textbf{x})$. How do we get exponentials like in the first row and second column $(-b_{12} e^{\lambda \tau})$? I mean we do $ \lambda I - A $ but we have $\lambda$ values at non-diagonal indices. How does it happen?